# why doesn't git use global email in .gitconfig?

Tags: bitbucket

I have set git configs in ~/.gitconfig as

```
[user]
        name = david_abc
        email = davidz@abclabs.com
```

But when I push to a repository:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': david_abc
Password for 'https://david_abc@bitbucket.org':
```

My question is why it doesn't recognize the name and email in the .gitconfig file.

Comment: each repository could have a different authentication. i tend to use crypto keys for git rather than user/pass, and use a lot of repositories with different logins

Comment: It is using the name -- `david_abc`. The string `david_abc@bitbucket.org` isn't an email address, but indicates authenticating against bitbucket with the username `david_abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not use `user.name` for HTTP authentication, it is just user name that will be written in commits made by that user.

See [git-credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) documentation for different options how to configure git to remember usernames (and eventually passwords) for repos.